# Drupal 7 custom module gives 403

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

i am having some troubles with my custom drupal 7 module. Notice, this is not my first module. This is my hook_menu;

```
function blog_contact_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items["blog_contact/send_to_one"] = array(
    "page_callback"=>"single_blogger_contact",
    "access_arguments"=>array("access blog_contact content"),
    "type"=>MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
}
```

And this is my perm function;

```
function blog_contact_perm() {
    return array("access blog_contact content");
}
```

This should work but when i do a ajax call, it gives 403 forbidden. You are not authorized to view bla bla. My ajax call is correct and simple, the url is correct, type is post. I don't see the reason directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties in menu router items have spaces in them instead of underscores. `access_arguments` should actually be `access arguments`, `page_arguments` should be `page arguments`, etc.:

```
function blog_contact_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items["blog_contact/send_to_one"] = array(
    "title" => "Title",
    "page callback"=>"single_blogger_contact",
    "access arguments"=>array("access blog_contact content"),
    "type"=>MENU_CALLBACK
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Also note that `title` is a required property.

Apart from that and the `hook_permission()` problem already mentioned your code is spot on.

Comment: Good catch! I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify an [`access_callback`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in your `hook_menu` implementation, it is using the [`user_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) function by default and checking to see if you have `access blog_contact content` permission granted.

```
function blog_contact_menu(){
    $items = array();
    $items["blog_contact/send_to_one"] = array(
    // As mentioned in Clive's answer, you should provide a title 
    "title" => "Your Title goes here",
    "page callback"=>"single_blogger_contact",
    // No "access callback" so uses user_access function by default
    "access arguments"=>array("access blog_contact content"),
    "type"=>MENU_CALLBACK
    );
```

The `access blog_contact content` is not a permission that Drupal knows about so the `user_access` function returns false which is why you're getting 403 access denied.

If you want to tell Drupal about `access blog_contact content` permission, then the hook is [`hook_permission`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7), not `hook_perm`.

And your code should be more like:

```
function blog_contact_permission() {
  return array(
    'access blog_contact content' => array(
      'title' => t('Access blog_contact content'), 
      'description' => t('Enter your description here.'),
    ),
  );
}
```